# How to remove a URL's trailing slash in a Rails app? (in a SEO view)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seo, url-rewriting

In order to avoid content duplication, I would like to avoid the pages of my site being accessible by several URLs  (with or without trailing slash).

Currently, the URLs

```
catalog/product/1
```

and

```
catalog/product/1/
```

lead to the same page. My goal is that the second URL redirect to the first (redirection 301, of course). None page of my site should be accessible with a trailing slash, except my home page / obviously.

What is the best way to do this? Using .htaccess or routes.rb? How would you do that?

NB: I'm developing with Ruby on Rails 1.2.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use [Apache's mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT:** Added R=301. I'm guessing there is an SEO advantage to that vs. the default 302.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tested it and observed a strange behaviour : it rewrites the URL adding the absolute path of the page! For instance, if I try to access to http://www.mysite.com/test/, it redirects to http://www.mysite.com/home/mysite/public_html/test !! Do you understand that?

Comment: Hmm, you might need to add "RewriteBase /" before the RewriteRule line.

Answer (score 16):

You could use http://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite for url rewriting to be independent from differences in web-servers.

Example usage in rails application:

```
config.gem 'rack-rewrite', '~> 1.0.0'
require 'rack/rewrite'
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do
  r301 %r{(.+)/$}, '$1'
end
```

Comment: In Rails 4, you'll need to replace `Rack::Lock` with `Rack::Runtime` (or another), as `Rack::Lock` is not present in the multi-threaded Rails environment enabled by default in Rails 4.

Comment: This doesn't remove trailing `/` when there is a query parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the rack-rewrite gem.   Here's how: http://nanceskitchen.com/2010/05/19/seo-heroku-ruby-on-rails-and-removing-those-darn-trailing-slashes/

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a redirect using routes.rb.  I suppose you could build a controller that just issues redirects and point all URLs ending in '/' to it, but that seems needlessly complicated.  Instead, I'd use mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```