# "No such middleware to insert before: Rack::Lock (RuntimeError)" after upgrading to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting the following error after upgrading to Rails 4:

`.../ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:125:in 'assert_index': No such middleware to insert before: Rack::Lock (RuntimeError)`

The offending line is my "[remove slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3570233/72176)" rack-rewrite rule:

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do
  r301 %r{^/(.*)/$}, '/$1', :headers => {'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age='+2.week.to_s}
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As the error suggests ("No such middleware to insert before"), the issue is with the middleware you are trying to *insert **before*** (and not the middleware you are trying to *insert*, which was my initial assumption).

In Rails4, threading is enabled by default which removes `Rack::Lock`.

To find a replacement, you can run `rake middleware` from your rails project directory, and look for something near the start of the stack. I'm going to pick `Rack::Runtime` as it is early in the stack, and seems pretty standard.

So the rewrite config is now:

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do
  r301 %r{^/(.*)/$}, '/$1', :headers => {'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age='+2.week.to_s}
end
```

Comment: Just one thing that confused me for a while was `rake middleware` was returning the full list of expected middleware including `Rack::Lock` and yet my rspec tests were failing due to not finding `Rack::Lock`.

In the end I realised (by inspecting config.middleware directly) that rspec was of course not loading the full stack of middleware.

I therefore moved the rewrites to `config/environments/production.rb` as I wouldn't be testing these redirects in rspec anyway.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out! The resource you're linking to in your answer no longer exists unfortunately.

Comment: In my case I needed to put `config.middleware.insert_before Rack::Runtime, Rack::LiveReload`, which may be specifically for Rails >=6. [Details are here in the `rack-livereload` README](https://github.com/jaredmdobson/rack-livereload#rails)