# No light as to how to trace this error on a migration to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been migrating a legacy app into newer versions of rails. The issue I have now is that I come up with this error when I try to bring the console up:

```
$ rails c
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:108:in `assert_index': No such middleware to insert after: "ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions" (RuntimeError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:82:in `insert_after'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/configuration.rb:71:in `block in merge_into'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/configuration.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/configuration.rb:70:in `merge_into'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:509:in `block in app'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:506:in `synchronize'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:506:in `app'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    from /home/user/Projects/firelight/firelight/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:28:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:95:in `perform'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I'm using Rails 5.2.5 with ruby 2.3.3 for now.
The error stacktrace isn't telling me anything significant at least nothing that I can determine.

Could I kindly get some pointers as to where can a good place to look be?

Edit: I linked to a post that has an answer to this. Basically if this error happens a good way is to look at the gems to see if there is a specific gem that needs to be upgraded.

Comment: The answer here should help you debug this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131366/no-such-middleware-to-insert-before-racklock-runtimeerror-after-upgrading

Comment: It did! Please post that as a response to give you credit.

Comment: Tis all good no worries, glad it's solved!